# Custom jackson bean serializer that can dynamically ignore some annotated properties based on the value of a sibling property

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, customserializer

So I have this java type called MyClass and it has some properties to serialize. It also has another property that decides whether the other properties should serialize or not. Is it possible to write a custom serializer to implement this rule, i.e. it will serialize the properties of the java type only if they match the condition? e.g. I have another sibling property which holds a list of ids. If the current property to serialize has an id assigned (via an annotation) that is part of that list, then I don't want to serialize it.

My java class...

```
public class MyClass implements WithFieldsToHide {

  // serializable fields

  @FieldId(id = "one")
  private String name;

  @FieldId(id = "two")
  private String company;

  public String getName() { return name; }

  public String getCompany() { return company; }


  // internal fields, non-serializable

  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<String> fieldsToHide;

  public Set<String> getFieldsToHide() { return fieldsToHide; }

}
```

A simple interface supporting fields to hide...

```
public interface WithFieldsToHide {
  Set<String> getFieldsToHide();
}
```

The simple annotation...

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface FieldId {
  String id();
}
```

Usage...

```
public static void main(String args...) {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  MyClass testObject = new MyClass();

  // assume the setters are available
  testObject.setName("Jackson");
  testObject.setCompany("NoBitMedia");
  testObject.setFieldsToHide(new HashSet<String>() {{ add("two"); }});

  String serialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testObject);
  // serialized should equal `{"name":"Jackson"}`
}
```

Few things I've tried:

- I can extend `BeanSerializerModifier` and override `modifySerializer()`, but I don't have the actual object available to be able to read that `fieldsToHide` property (on the basis of which I'll decide whether to serialize or not).
- I can write a custom converter (extend `StdConverter<MyClass, MyClass>`, but i don't have the properties list of the annotations in the `convert()` method.
- I can write a custom serializer (`MyClassSerializer<T extends WithFieldsToHide> extends JsonSerializer<T>`), but here too, I'm not sure if i'll have the property list and their annotations available in the `serialize()` method.

Before I try to dig in more into jackson code, wanted to ask if this kind of dynamic serialization is possible at all.. or any suggestions that can get me similar results?

Comment: I think I found an answer after spending some more time. Will post it in a bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did try overriding the `BeanPropertyWriter` earlier but couldn't really figure it all out together how to do what I wanted to do.

Here is what I did finally.

Interface to implement if the bean class needs to hide it's fields dynamically..

```
public interface WithFieldsToHide {
  boolean hide(String fieldId);
}
```

Annotation to put on the fields that need to be hidden..

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface HideFieldId {
  String id();
}
```

```
public class CustomFieldHideModule extends Module {
  @Override
  public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
    context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new CustomFieldHideSerializerModifier());
  }

  private static class CustomFieldHideSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
      // only try to hide fields for class of a particular interface type
      if (WithFieldsToHide.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())) {
        for (int i = 0; i < beanProperties.size(); i++) {
          BeanPropertyWriter writer = beanProperties.get(i);
          // to be able to run the logic to hide, we need to know if the property has a field id assigned
          HideFieldId annotation = writer.getAnnotation(HideFieldId.class);
          if (null != annotation) {
            beanProperties.set(i, new ConditionalPropertyWriter<>(writer, annotation.id()));
          }
        }
      }
      return beanProperties;
    }

    private static class ConditionalPropertyWriter<T extends WithFieldsToHide> extends BeanPropertyWriter{

      private final fieldId;
      protected ConditionalPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyWriter writer, String fieldId) {
        super(writer);
        this.fieldId = fieldId;
      }

      @Override
      public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
        T withFieldsToHide = (T) bean; // don't need type check as we're checking when registering this writer for the property
        if (!withFieldsToHide.isInternal(fieldId)) {
          super.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, prov);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you just register this module with your object mapper, and voila!

I also wanted one more level of hiding, for map property types where i only needed to hide certain elements in the map property and not the whole property itself, and could write something to achieve it. Let me know if anyone wants that, not including it for brevity.

Thanks!!